# Sentential Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Below is a question comes from the book *How to Prove It* written by Daniel J. Velleman.

> Let $P$ stand for the statement, “I will buy the pants” and $S$ for the statement “I will buy the shirt.” What English sentences are represented by the following expressions?
>
> $\lnot(P \land \lnot S)$

The given answer is, “I won't buy the pants without the shirt.“
I don't understand the answer. Can someone explain? Or maybe the answer is wrong?

Comment: It represents "if I will buy the pants, then I will buy the shirt."  Oops... perhaps, but not necessarily (the part in quotes is half a joke).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that, by [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),
$$\lnot (A\land B)\iff(\lnot A\lor\lnot B),$$
so
$$\lnot (P\land \lnot S)\iff \lnot P\lor(\lnot\lnot S)\iff\lnot P\lor S.$$
Our goal is to describe what it means for $\lnot (P\land \lnot S)$ to be true. So, let's agree that it is true, and see what we conclude.

If you don't buy the pants, then $\lnot P$ is true, and hence so is $\lnot P\lor S$, regardless of what $S$ is. However, if you do buy the pants, then $\lnot P$ is false, and in this case, the only way $\lnot P \lor S$ can be true is if $S$ is true, i.e. if you buy the shirt.

Thus, to say that $\lnot (P\land \lnot S)$ is true is to say that maybe you won't buy the pants, maybe you will; but if you do, you'll definitely also buy the shirt.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation!

Comment: A minor point is that the question appears on p. 14 of Velleman (2nd ed.), whereas DeMorgan's laws are not mentioned until p. 20.

Answer (score 6):

Let's work from the inside out:

- $S$ means: "I will buy the shirt."
- $\neg S$ means: "I **won't** buy the shirt."
- $P \land \neg S$ means: "I will buy the pants **and** I won't buy the shirt." Another way to say this is: "I will buy the pants **but not** the shirt." (or, equivalently, "I will buy the pants **without** the shirt.").
- $\neg(P \land \neg S)$ means: "I **won't** buy the pants without the shirt."

Due to the ambiguity of the English language, there will certainly be multiple "translations" and no unique "answer". Later on, you might learn that:
$$
\neg(P \land \neg S) \quad \equiv \quad \neg P \lor S \quad \equiv \quad P \rightarrow S
$$
Thus, a (perhaps more intuitive) valid translation of $\neg(P \land \neg S)$ would be: "**If** I buy the pants, **then** I must also buy the shirt."

Comment: Can you give other translation for ¬(P∧¬S) other than 'I won't buy the pants without the shirt' and 'If I buy the pants, then I must also buy the shirt.' Assuming one doesn't know ¬(P∧¬S)≡¬P∨S≡P→S, how can he reason the answer to be so?

Comment: @DaveClifford Other translations include "It is not the case that I  will buy the pants but not the shirt." and "Either I will buy the shirt or I won't buy the pants (or I will do both and buy the shirt without the pants)." In general, to see why these statements are true, it helps to construct a truth table (that is, consider all possible combinations of truth values of $P$ and $S$ and see if a proposed English translation is consistent with whatever Boolean value that the expression evaluates to).

Comment: Oh, the translation 'it is not the case that I will buy the pants but not the shirt' makes sense to me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: You might want to note that you don't necessarily need the intermediate step of "¬P∨S" to prove the equivalence (¬(P∧¬S)≡(P→S)) here, at least in some logical calculi, where it holds.

Comment: For those reading Velleman in order without glancing ahead, note that truth tables are introduced in the following section (1.2).